# TypeError: .offset(...) is undefined

Tags: jquery, typeerror

can't understand whats wrong whit my code.
Im my js:

```
var full_url = window.location.href;
    var parts = full_url.split("#");
    var trgt = parts[1];
    if (trgt) {
        var aTag = jQuery("a[name='" + trgt + "']");
        jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top}, 'slow');
```

I get this error:

**TypeError: aTag.offset(...) is undefined ...jQuery("html,body").animate({scrollTop:aTag.offset().top},"slow")}}jQuery("body"...**

The url is something like this:

http://www.myurl/my-link/#backnumber

Im my html:

```
<a name="backnumber"></a>
```

Thanks

Comment: Except for a missing } , your code works fine. https://jsfiddle.net/ouw6edkz/

Comment: Should be, but dosent :(

Comment: have you declared the markup after the script ? If so, you need to declare the markup first and then the script

Answer (score 1):

This tells you that as of when the

```
var aTag = jQuery("a[name='" + trgt + "']");
```

line ran, there was no matching element, and so jQuery gave you back an empty set. When you call `offset()` on an empty set, you get back `undefined`, and so you get an error trying to read its `.top` property.

Comment: I think he's arguing that `aTag` shouldn't be undefined as the `a` tag apparently exists in his HTML and he's calling it with a location hash as seen by the start of the script. Essentially the _real_ issue is that jQuery isn't finding his `a` tag.

Comment: Why should be  no matching element?  console.log(aTag); dosent not return undefined, but the html a tag

Comment: @matt: As of the line above, apparently it doesn't. That's the only situation in which `offset` returns `undefined`.